# Autoware: 1.12.0 Download error and dependencies problem

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Operating system and version:
Ubuntu 18.04
gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
cmake version 3.10.2
ROS distribution:
melodic
ROS installation type:
sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-desktop-full

[link text](https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/autoware/wikis/Source-Build)
Since I am using melodic I tried to get 1.12.0 version of autoware (I am reinstalling autoware since my ubuntu got crashed and again i am reinstalling everything and i installed everything), since Autoware shifted it from github to gitlab i am following the above mentioned tutorial; and i am facing multiple issues

```
sudo apt install -y python-catkin-pkg python-rosdep rosdep-$ROS_DISTRO-catkin
[sudo] password for sai: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package rosdep-melodic-catkin
```

the other problem is

```
~/autoware.ai$ wget -O autoware.ai.repos https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/autoware/raw/1.12.0/autoware.ai.repos?inline=false
--2019-06-26 18:19:28--  https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/autoware/raw/1.12.0/autoware.ai.repos?inline=false
Resolving gitlab.com (gitlab.com)... 35.231.145.151
Connecting to gitlab.com (gitlab.com)|35.231.145.151|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2019-06-26 18:19:29 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

When I downloaded the master version and tried to build I am getting the citysim package failed to build.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327055/autoware:-1.12.0-download-error-and-dependencies-problem/) by [AM97](https://answers.ros.org/users/41623/am97/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2019-06-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-26**:\

> ```
> E: Unable to locate package rosdep-melodic-catkin
> ```

The package name is `ros-melodic-catkin`, not `rosdep-melodic-catkin`.

**Comment by [AM97](https://answers.ros.org/users/41623/am97/) on 2019-06-26**:
@gvdhoorn Yes I thought the same and I tried to install but I am getting this ros-melodic-catkin is already the newest version so the package is already installed but rosdep means it is about dependencies right??

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-26**:\

> I am getting this ros-melodic-catkin is already the newest version so the package is already installed

yes, so that is not a problem at all.

> but rosdep means it is about dependencies right??

I don't understand what this means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The wiki seems to be updated and has correct commands now.
The commands are now :

`sudo apt install -y python-catkin-pkg python-rosdep ros-$ROS_DISTRO-catkin`

and

`$ wget -O autoware.ai.repos https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/autoware/raw/1.12.0-alpha.2/autoware.ai.repos?inline=false`

FYI, current v.1.12 is alpha-2 release. The official release will be on 8 July, 2019 so it might be worth waiting if you want to use stable version. https://discourse.ros.org/t/dates-for-1-12-development-and-release/8513/9

Of course you are welcome to test the alpha release and report issues as well.

---

Originally posted by [mitsudome-r](https://answers.ros.org/users/41790/mitsudome-r/) with karma: 231 on 2019-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AM97](https://answers.ros.org/users/41623/am97/) on 2019-06-27**:
I have updated it and was able to download 1.12.0 alpha tag but later I am getting a new issue which I have generated new issue (http://answers.ros.org/question/327117/autoware-1120-build-error/) Anyway I will update to alpha-2 after it is released but in this time I wanted to work using 1.12 alpha1 so that I can get aware of autoware usage. Thanks for the help.